# Hold a participant during Conference in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

According to [this Twilio documnetation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent), a webhook to the URL specified in the 'statusCallback' attribute will be generated on the six events. Of these, when will the 'hold' event be triggered?
And, How to hold a particular participant during a Conference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

The 'hold' event will be fired when 'a participant has been held or unheld'.

To 'hold' or 'unhold' a participant to a conference you will make a POST request to the participant SID (the attribute `"Hold = True/False"`).

The request will look something like this:

```
$POST /Conference/CFbbe46ff1274e283f7e3ac1df0097ab39/Participants/CA386025c9bf5d6052a1d1ea42b4d16662
    -d "Hold=True" \
    -d "HoldUrl=https://myapp.com/hold" \
    -u 'AC123:{AuthToken}'
```

More about this:

- https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/introducing-conference-hold.html
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant